# Responsive site giving me trouble, chrome positioning a div in a different area?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

http://www.remotegoatdesign.com/sayhey/pages/edit-valentines-marc-card.html
Doing this site for an assignment due tomorrow. In the proccess of making it responsive.
I am having an issue with the last color block, although its put into its container using percentages, it keeps moving out. In chrome its outside it straight away, whereas in Firefox its only when I resize. Although the difference is only a few pixels, so I'd assume its to do with the monitor size.
Any ideas guys? I'm stumped.

Comment: First of all, go fix your [HTML errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.remotegoatdesign.com/sayhey/pages/edit-valentines-marc-card.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add this code snippet into your css file.

```
#tab-1 > div > div 
{
width: 8%;
}
```

You can change the width.

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

try putting slightly smaller percentages(in the color block) and test it until it looks good. also it fits right in wider monitors as you say, because you have one css, that is best for wide screens. the point of responsive design is to have more than one media queries if the one you have breaks the design in smaller screens. so either make the color blocks really small, or myou should make more media queries

Comment: tried that, still happens :( they are sized right because it fits on a wider monitor, something happens when it gets smaller that pushes the last block out.

Comment: for my screen it work fine when i put  in the .box {width: 8.24%;} but then it looks kinda ugly. the best solution i believe is to put the color blocks inside a wrapper div, that is about 94% of the parent, and then make it centered(with margin:0 auto;) and make the color blocks inside them small enough.  (edit: or you could give the .color_container { text-align:center;} and then the color blocks width:about 8.1%, i dont think it can fail that way)

Answer (score 0):

Try using property " display:inline-table " for the class color_container
and give margin for the smaller color divs for space inbetween

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is display: inline-block;. When you use it, it adds an extra space between elements. If you want to sort out this, you have 2 fixes:

a) negative margin-right

.box {

```
display: inline-block; 
width: 8.74%;
height: 100%;
margin-right: -4px;
```

}

b) font-size: 0; on the container and default font-size on the elements inside

.color_container {

```
width: 98%;
height: 60px;
min-height: 60px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #fff;
font-size: 0;
```

}

.box {

```
display: inline-block; 
width: 8.74%;
height: 100%;
font-size: 1em; /* or what is your default font-size */
```

}